# R: How to extract all labels in a certain node of a dendrogram

Tags: r, nodes, label, dendrogram, members

I am writing a program that (as a part of it) automatically creates dendrograms from an input dataset.
For **each** node/split I want to extract **all** the labels that are under that node **and** the location of that node on the dendrogram plot (for further plotting purposes).
So, let's say my data looks like this:

```
> Ltrs <- data.frame("A" = c(3,1), "B" = c(1,1), "C" = c(2,4), "D" = c(6,6))
> dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(Ltrs))))
> plot(dend)
```

[The dendrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htOwT.png)

Now I can extract the location of the splits/nodes:

```
> library(dendextend)
> nodes <- get_nodes_xy(dend)
> nodes <- nodes[nodes[,2] != 0, ]
> nodes
      [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 1.875 7.071068
[2,] 2.750 3.162278
[3,] 3.500 2.000000
```

Now I want to get all the labels under a node, for each node (/row from the 'nodes' variable).

This should look something like this:

```
$`1`
[1] "D" "C" "B" "A"

$`2`
[1] "C" "B" "A"

$`3 `
[1] "B" "A"
```

Can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I find working with the dendrogram structure very confusing. It probably would be much easier to work with the `hclust` object and `cutree`. You cut e.g. loop different `k` options to get to the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dendextend)
Ltrs <- data.frame("A" = c(3,1), "B" = c(1,1), "C" = c(2,4), "D" = c(6,6))
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(Ltrs))))

accumulator <- list();
myleaves <- function(anode){
    if(!is.list(anode))return(attr(anode,"label"))
    accumulator[[length(accumulator)+1]] <<- (reduce(lapply(anode,myleaves),c))
}

myleaves(dend);
ret <- rev(accumulator); #generation was depth first, so root was found last.
```

Better test this. I am not very trustworthy. In particular, I really hope the list ret is in an order that makes sense, otherwise it's going to be a pain associating the entries with the correct nodes! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Indeed the order of the ret list is a bit weird. I think it is the same order as in the hclust$merge variable. I will have look into it that, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Function `partition_leaves()` extracts all leaf labels per each node and makes a list ordered in the same fashion as `get_nodes_xy()` output. With your example,

```
Ltrs <- data.frame("A" = c(3,1), "B" = c(1,1), "C" = c(2,4), "D" = c(6,6))
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(Ltrs))))
plot(dend)

partition_leaves(dend)
```

yields:

```
[[1]]
[1] "D" "C" "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "D"

[[3]]
[1] "C" "A" "B"

[[4]]
[1] "C"

[[5]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[6]]
[1] "A"

[[7]]
[1] "B"
```

filtering list by vector length will give output similar to the desired one.